# How to call member functions from onClickListeners

Tags: java, android

Consider the below piece of code (which works fine by the way) from an `Activity`:

```
class ParentActivity extends Activity {
    ...       

    @Override
    public void btnOK_onClick(final View view) {
        // do stuff
    }

}

class ChildActivity extends ParentActivity {
    ...

    public void superClick(View view) {
        super.btnOK_onClick(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void btnOK_onClick(final View view) {
        final BarcodePickActivity me = this;
        if (confirmation_needed == true) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(R.string.are_you_sure_)
            .setMessage(R.string.are_you_sure_you_want_to_continue)
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, null)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    me.superClick(view);
                }
            }).create().show();
        } else {
            super.btnOK_onClick(view);
        }
    }
}
```

In the layout that is used, there is a `Button` with an `onClick` set:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOK"
        android:onClick="btnOK_onClick"
        android:text="@string/ok" />
```

as you see, I have to jump through quite some hoops to get this working:

1. define a `final` variable to have `this` available in the `OnClickListener` of the `AlertDialog`,
2. define an extra method to be able to call `super.btnOk_onClick`.

As I said, it works fine, but it doesn't look pretty. Is there a way to do this nicer?

Comment: Please post the full code as this does not make sense.

Comment: @AdamArold I added some code that hopefully makes it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `classname.this` from the inner class. So if you class is `MySuperClass` you can reference `MySuperClass.this` from an instance inner class.

There is no reason you need to define `superClick` as you could always just call `super.btnOK_onClick(view);`.

So all told, you should be able to do something like `MySuperClass.super.btnOK_onClick()`

Comment: `this.super` does not compile, but `ChildActivity.super.btnOnClick()` seems to work

Comment: have you tried calling `super.btnOK_onClick` from the inner class? That MIGHT work. If not you will still have to define `superClick`. Either way you can get rid of `me`.

Comment: @MikeM. I don't think so, as I want to call the "base" method in the overridden method. Calling without `super` would cause an stackoverflow.

Comment: @MikeM. Bart is right, he is trying to call the overridden method from the overridding method. The way to do this is with `super`.

Comment: I apologize. You are correct in that. I'd forgotten that you overrode `btnOK_onClick()`. However, as I say in my answer, if the stuff done doesn't depend on the View parameter, put it in its own method.

Comment: @JohnB if you update your answer to use `ChildActivity.super.onBtnOK_Click`, I'll accept it. It rids both `me` and `superClick()`.

Comment: Doh! yeah should have thought of that. Answer updated.